# Can't find my friend to trade with in Warframe

Tags: technical-issues, warframe

I'm trying to trade with a friend I have (we are friends in *Warframe* as well). We are also in the same clan, and both above Mastery Rank 2.

However, although we can both see each other (in relays), we can't find each other in the chat, or see messages that the other has posted. And when we go to the trading menu, we can't find each other there either. We can see each other's profiles though.

My friend plays on pc, and I play on the Switch.

We also can't trade in the clan dojo because my clan key only just started printing.

And just to clear up any possible misconceptions, it's not that it's not letting us trade specific items, it's that we can't find each other to trade in the trade menus.

Also, (and I'm not sure if this relates or not), we were originally going to trade in Maroo's Bazaar on Mars, but while it showed the various different instances for my friend, it wouldn't show me any instances; it just started the countdown in the top left to announce I would be going there in ~5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have cross platform save account, stated in
[official cross-platform save/trading post](https://forums.warframe.com/topic/1374265-cross-platform-save-rollout-information-status/):

> To make sure you can trade with friends or fellow Tenno across platforms, be sure you are using a Cross Platform Save Account (or PC account*) and have Cross Platform Play enabled via your in-game settings.

Which you have to connect at least one account other than Nintendo (recommend using PC), stated in [here](https://www.warframe.com/news/cross-platform-save):

> Q: What is a Cross Platform Save Account?
>
> This simply refers to any Warframe account that has undergone Linking or Merging in order to connect two or more accounts for use in Cross Platform Save.

Note that you cannot trade Platinum between Nintendo Switch and other Platforms (which means most of trade is practically not available since almost of all trades are trade of items (mods, parts blueprint, etc...) and plats).

> Tenno can trade with players on different platforms (depending on those players’ Cross Platform settings). Trading will function the same as gifting, except for trading Platinum between Nintendo Switch and other platforms, which is not available.